# routes issues in layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ok so i'm getting this error -
No route matches {:action=>"search", :controller=>"drawings", :search=>"2016"} missing required keys: [:workcategory_id]

I have this in my layouts/_header

```
      <% unless @workcategories.nil? %>
        <% @workcategories.each do |workcategory| %>
          <li><%= link_to workcategory.name, search_workcategory_drawings_path(search: workcategory.name) %></li>
        <% end %>
```

my drawing model

```
belongs_to :workcategory
def self.search(params)
    drawings = Drawing.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")
    drawings
end
```

and this is the part of the controller where things should be happening

```
def search
    @drawings = Drawing.search(params)
end
```

lastly my routes

```
  resources :workcategories do
    resources :drawings do
      collection do
        get :search
      end
    end
  end
```

So the issue is, that when i go on any page - home, admin panel etc .. i get that error 'No route matches {:action=>"search", :controller=>"drawings", :search=>"2016"} missing required keys: [:workcategory_id]'. I don't understand why it's trying to 'build' the search path already, although i'm not trying to access it. I hope i'm making sense ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply provide a `workcategory_id` :

```
      <li><%= link_to workcategory.name, search_workcategory_drawings_path(workcategory.id, search: workcategory.name) %></li>
```

Comment: Oh WOW really that was all ? God that was lame ... now i have the other problem where the search isn't working actually, so when i pick the year, it doesn't show me anything, got any idea for that as well ?

Comment: oh nevermind i figured that out, i had to search for the workcategory.id not .name. Thanks ! You got the answer right ^^